# C++ Builder 10 CoreFondation.h(12): 'Stdarg.h' file not found

Tags: c++, ios, c++builder

[image]
Trying to run this app but it keeps on giving me this error.  CoreFondation.h(12): 'Stdarg.h' file not found.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7.3 and iOS 9.3 are not supported. I had to uninstall XCode 7.3 and reinstall XCode 7.2.1 (actual official version). Then the supported iOS 9.2 SDK will be created and it worked

Comment: I‘m having the same problem with RAD 10.3.1 now, any idea which Xcode and iOS SDK version I need or how to find out?